# How to wrap a td with anchor tag on datatables plugin

Tags: jquery

I have a using `jquery-datatable` Serverside. Everything is working fine, but I want to add anchor tag on one coloumn for which I am doing like this:

```
$('td:eq(1)', nRow).wrap('<a href="/hello/"/>');
```

which is resulting in the following error:

`sCurrentClass = nTds[i].className;`

I want anchor tag with the value of specific row like:

```
<a href="ok">ok</a>
<a href="hello">hello</a>
```

--> `hello and ok` are the values

How to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.append()` instead of `.wrap()`

```
 $('td:eq(1)', nRow).append('<a href="hello">hello</a>');
```

Comment: `hello` is autopopulated by the datatables.

Comment: `aData[1]` contains all the values of 2nd coloumn.

Comment: You mean to say hello comes from `aData[1].className`??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for wrap to [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
$('td:eq(1)', nRow).contents().wrap('<a href="/hello/" />');
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want but Each row has the different values. `hello` should be replaced by the value of particular row which is populated by data table.

Comment: the value is wrapped with a tag like if you have <td>hello</td> then the result would be <td><a href="">hello</a></td>